# Flutter - _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class BrewList extends StatefulWidget {
  const BrewList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BrewList> createState() => _BrewListState();
}

class _BrewListState extends State<BrewList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final brews = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot?>(context);
    // print(brews?.docs);
    
    for (var doc in brews!.docs) {
      print(doc.data);
    }

    return Container();
  }
}
```

I'm getting ax exception saying:

> _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

What do I do then?

Comment: Hi, it may complain that the `brews` is null

Comment: @Lebecca yes it does say

Answer (score 2):

I put comments in the code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class BrewList extends StatefulWidget {
  const BrewList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BrewList> createState() => _BrewListState();
}

class _BrewListState extends State<BrewList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // NOTE: Before accessing Provider, make sure that it DOES EXIST on the widget tree. The provided code snippet does not have it.
    final brews = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot?>(context);
    // print(brews?.docs);
    
    // If the Provider does not exist, then brews would be NULL and you'll have the error when force dereferencing it.
    for (var doc in brews!.docs) {
      print(doc.data);
    }

    return Container();
  }
}
```

If you are not sure where to put the Provider, or if you believe that you have put the provider somewhere else, maybe you can share the relevant objective/code.

Comment: https://github.com/iamshaunjp/flutter-firebase/blob/lesson-18/brew_crew/lib/screens/home/home.dart

Check it in here. I'm following his tutorial

Comment: @Kvu In the tutorial, we put a StreamProvider in the widget tree (line 14), and passed BrewList (the widget that uses the provider) as the body, so if you follow his example verbatim it should be good.
In any case, just make sure that the Provider is the parent or ancestor of the widget that uses it.